# XMLHttpRequest for Riot API with React App and got No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I could search many questions / answers from Stackoverflow but... It was too difficult for me to understand. I understood the core issue / cause. I am running on localhost:3000 and it is different than riot domain ("https://developer.riotgames.com") so it gives an error.

However... all the answers and guidances are too difficult for me to understand. Here is my code:

```
let req = "https://na.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/NA/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + "<some name>" + "?api_key=<apikey>";

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
let result = "";
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    result = this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", req, true);
xhttp.send();
console.log(result);
```

So basically I just want to run this simple request to Riot to get JSON response... but it gives me :
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

Would you please let me know how I can resolve it? Please make it easy to understand :(  Thank you so much.

Comment: you need appropriate CORS headers on the server side - but I guess you have no access to `developer.riotgames.com` to put those appropriate headers in ... so ... you'll need to proxy the requests through your server on `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: see https://discussion.developer.riotgames.com/questions/106/why-am-i-getting-an-access-control-allow-origin-er.html